# CSS/JS positioning a button in dynamic ul

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I have a dropdown menu with `ul` and `li` structure as below:

```
<ul class="container"> 
    <span class="content_container"><!-- Empty --></span>
    <span class="fixed_area">Fixed Button</span>
</ul>
```

Then in JS, I simply append dynamic `li` to the `content_container`:

```
$('span.content_container').html(li_content);
```

Giving...

```
<ul class="container">
    <span class="content_container">
       <li>Something</li>
       <!-- and so on dynamically -->
    </span>
    <span class="fixed_area">Fixed Button</span>
</ul>
```

I am trying to position a fixed area with a button as below image:

[image]

The `ul` has max height of 800px. When there are lots of `li`, then it is fairly simple to position the `fixed_area` button as below:

```
span.fixed_area {
   height: 48px;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: red;
   top: 750px;
}
```

I can simply position the fixed button to the bottom of the max height container.

**The problem:**

The problem is that since I am getting the `li` dynamically, there are times when not enough `li` is loaded, yet the fixed button is still positioned at `top:750px`, thus often not visible or misplaced.

**What I am trying to do:**

I can re-structure the html portion. I need to position the fixed button always at the bottom of the visible container regardless how long the lists are as shown in image, both A and B.

Hope this makes sense.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it required that the button be 'inside' the scrolling portion?  Since you say you can restructure the html, what if you just moved the button html outside the ul and positioned it directly underneath.

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: bad choice of using position fixed of a div in a ul tag...position fixed is relative to viewport....you prefer another solution with javascript?

Comment: @roger Yeah, I am giving that a try and see how it looks.

Comment: And @repzero I will love to look at the js solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could constraint only the `.content_container` and let the button right below it.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="content_container">
       <li>Something</li>
       <!-- and so on dynamically -->
    </ul>
    <span class="fixed_area">Fixed Button</span>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.content_container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 750px; // reduced because it doesn't count the button.
}
```

You don't need any position:

```
.fixed_area {
   display: inline-block; // if you want to set the height;
   height: 48px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a list name in the  input box and press button to append it to the menu. That fixed button is still at the bottom while the options are being added at the top.

```js
document.getElementById('press').addEventListener('click', press);
ul_container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
dummy = document.getElementById('dummy');
var inp = document.getElementById('in');

function press() {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = inp.value;
  console.log(ul_container, dummy, div)
  ul_container.insertBefore(div, dummy);

}
```

```css
.container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
.container:hover {
  display: auto;
}
#menu {
  border: solid black;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
#fixed_btn,
#dummy {
  list-style-type: none
}
#fixed_btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: green;
}
#menu:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: none;
}
.container li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button id='press'>
  press
</button>
<input type="text" id="in">
<div id="menu">
  Menu Name
  <ul class="container">

    <li id="dummy"></li>

    <li id='fixed_btn'>BUTTON</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: note too that after ul tag exceeds max-height the ul becomes scrollable